# How can I change the color of the sidebar in Nautilus 3.2.0?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, themes

This used to be easy to do with a .gtkrc-2.0 in Ubuntu 11.04 and previous releases.  I am using a third-party theme (Elements) and I really like it, but the Nautilus sidebar is ugly and dark and I want it to match the rest of the theme a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to edit the css themes for the GTK+ 3 theme to accomplish this. You can use other themes (there many themes on gnomelook.org for you to look at).

Comment: Thanks! I've had a bit of success with this option, however not all GTK+3 themes look the same once you dig in and start editing them.  Although I was able to change the color of the sidebar, I have yet to determine how to then change the font color of the file tree in the sidebar.  But I'll figure it out eventually.